# Fast query when executed individually, slow when nested

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm trying to find the most recent entry time at a bunch of specific dates. When I run

```
select max(ts) as maxts from factorprice where ts <= '2011-1-5'
```

It returns very quickly.

EXPLAIN gives select_type SIMPLE and "Select tables optimized away".

But when I run

```
select (select max(ts) from factorprice where ts <= dates.dt) as maxts, dates.dt 
   from 
   trends.dates where dates.dt in ('2011-1-6');
```

It takes a long time to return (~10 seconds).

Explain gives:

- select_type=PRIMARY table=dates rows=506 Extra=Using where
- select_type=DEPENDENT SUBQUERY table=factorprice type=index
  possible_keys=PRIMARY    key=PRIMARY keylen=8 rows=26599224 Extra=Using
  where; Using index

This query also takes a long time (10 sec)

```
select dt, max(ts) as maxts from factorprice as f inner join trends.dates as d
   where ts <= dt and dt in ('2011-1-6')
   group by dt;
```

Explain gives:

- select_type=SIMPLE table=d type=ALL rows =509 Extra=Using where
- select_type=SIMPLE table=f type=range possible_keys=PRIMARY key=PRIMARY keylen=8 rows=26599224 Extra=Using
  where; Using index

I'd like to do this same operation on many different dates. Is there a way I can do that efficiently?

Comment: Add `EXPLAIN` in front of your query and see where the bottleneck occurs. Then post back so you receive better answers.

Comment: I'm guessing it's running the nested query for each row on `trends`. The join version may have a similar problem, since there is no ON condition for the join.

Comment: Is there an index on dates.dt?

Comment: bfavaretto: when I add a second date to the "in (...)" the second query takes twice as long as before.

Comment: Gruikya: There wasn't, so I added one but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this bug:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=32665

Maybe if you create an index on dates.dt, it will go away.

Comment: I didn't see any change in behavior after adding an index on dt. Is this a bit different because it shouldn't be cashing the subquery?

Comment: The MySQL query optimizer has some bugs on evaluating subquery execution path, and sometimes, adding indexes on the primary query table helps fix those bugs (even if said index shouldn't really help). Too bad it did not help, in this case.

Comment: By the way, did you create a UNIQUE index on dates.dt ? It seems to fix the problem on a test database I just created (but maybe it is pointless in your case, though).

Comment: I added both a PRIMARY and UNIQUE and neither seemed to change the behavior. :(

Answer (score 0):

This part of your SQL is a dependent query

```
select max(ts) from factorprice where ts <= dates.dt
```

which is executed for each row in the resultset. So the total time is approximately the time of the standalone query times the rows in the result set.

Comment: When I add a second date to the "in (...)" the second query takes twice as long as before.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your EXPLAIN output.  This query is visiting 506 rows in the dates table and then for each of those rows, over 26 million rows in the factorprice table.  10 seconds to do all of that isn't too bad.

My guess is that you are inadvertently creating a CROSS JOIN situation where every row of one table is matched up with every row in another table.